# Is it still possible to run javascript in the address bar

Tags: javascript

I used to be able to type javascript in the address bar like this: javascript:alert();. It doesn't work anymore. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Probably because too many people got tricked into executing malicious code this way.

Comment: People were being given "secret hacks" to put in their address bar that would "enable awesome Facebook features" and actually send their login cookies off to an attacker. Too widely abused, and now you've got the developer console for this.

Comment: I tried in Chrome Version 105.0.5195.127 (Official Build) (64-bit) and it works. Just need to type `javascript:` manually.

Comment: Does not work in Firefox v106.0b3

Comment: (Attack is known as Self-XSS; https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-XSS) Chrome's disabling: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82181; Firefox's: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=656433